# Как в PhpStorm сохранять куски кода и вешать на горячие клавиши без использования макросов?

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.
Как в PhpStorm сохранять куски кода и вешать на горячие клавиши без использования макросов? С макросами увы не получается подружиться, но очень хочется найти метод, который позволит сократить уйму времени.

Answer (score 2):

Без макросов нельзя пока не реализуют [этот запрос](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67811).

С макросами делается относительно несложно, я уже описывал процесс [на другом сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9639266/104891).

Comment: спасибо большое, разобрался, очень крутая шутка эта Live Templates, тоже что и зен-кодинг, вопрос с макросами просто отпал

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl + Alt + S** → **Editor** → **Live Templates** — создаете любые шаблоны/сниппеты.

Я разворачиваю по **Tab**.

Comment: спасибо! гениально